# change css according to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<html lang="en">
<head>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<li id="visa">
<section class="credit-card visa gr-visa">
        <div class="logo">visa</div>
        <form>
            <h2>Payment Details</h2>

            <ul class="inputs">
                <li>
                    <label>Card Number</label>
                    <input type="text" name="card_number" pattern="[0-9]{13,16}" value="9842 9472 9457 9472" class="full gr-input" required />
                </li>
          <li>
            <label>Name on card</label>
            <input type="text" name="card_name" size="20" class="month gr-input" required />
                <li class="expire last">
                    <label>Expiration</label>

                <div class="dropdown">
      <select name="one" class="dropdown-select month gr-input">
        <option value="">Month</option>
        <option value="1">Jan</option>
        <option value="2">Feb</option>
        <option value="3">Mar</option>
     <option value="4">Apr</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">Jun</option>
     <option value="7">Jul</option>
     <option value="8">Aug</option>
     <option value="9">Sep</option>
     <option value="10">Oct</option>
     <option value="11">Nov</option>
     <option value="12">Dec</option>

      </select>
    </div>          

            <div class="dropdown">
      <select name="one" class="dropdown-select year gr-input">
        <option value="">Year</option>
           <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
     <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
     <option value="2019">2019</option>
     <option value="2020">2020</option>
     <option value="2021">2021</option>
     <option value="2022">2022</option>
     <option value="2023">2023</option>
     <option value="2024">2024</option>
      </select>
    </div>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="cvc-code last">
                    <label>CVV Code</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cvc_code" value="174" size="10" class="gr-input" required />
                </li>
              <input type="post" name="submit" value="Pay Now" class="fsSubmitButton"/>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </ul>
        </form>
        <div class="watermark">visa</div>
    </section>
</li>
<li id="mastercard">
<section class="credit-card mastercard gr-mastercard">
        <div class="logo"><div></div><div></div></div>

        <form>
            <h2>Payment Details</h2>

            <ul class="inputs">
                <li>
                    <label>Card Number</label>
                    <input type="text" name="card_number" pattern="[0-9]{13,16}" value="9842 9472 9457 9472" class="full gr-input" required />
                </li>
          <li>
            <label>Name on card</label>
            <input type="text" name="card_name" size="20" class="month gr-input" required />
                <li class="expire last">
                    <label>Expiration</label>

                <div class="dropdown">
      <select name="one" class="dropdown-select month gr-input">
        <option value="">Month</option>
        <option value="1">Jan</option>
        <option value="2">Feb</option>
        <option value="3">Mar</option>
     <option value="4">Apr</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">Jun</option>
     <option value="7">Jul</option>
     <option value="8">Aug</option>
     <option value="9">Sep</option>
     <option value="10">Oct</option>
     <option value="11">Nov</option>
     <option value="12">Dec</option>

      </select>
    </div>          

            <div class="dropdown">
      <select name="one" class="dropdown-select year gr-input">
        <option value="">Year</option>
           <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
     <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
     <option value="2019">2019</option>
     <option value="2020">2020</option>
     <option value="2021">2021</option>
     <option value="2022">2022</option>
     <option value="2023">2023</option>
     <option value="2024">2024</option>
      </select>
    </div>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="cvc-code last">
                    <label>CVV Code</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cvc_code" value="174" size="10" class="gr-input" required />
                </li>
            <input type="post" name="submit" value="Pay Now" class="fsSubmitButtonM"/>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>

            </ul>
        </form>
        <div class="watermark"><div></div><div></div></div>
    </section>
</li>
```

two forms here..What I need is when I enter a number starting with 9,the first form should be showed,but if I enter 4 the visa form should be shown

the css is

```
/* === Basic reset === */
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: none; box-sizing:border-box; }
a>img { border: none; }
header, footer, article, section, nav, aside { display: block; }

/* === General === */
body {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    background:#ddd;
}

.clearfix {
    clear:both;
}
/* === Credit Card === */
.credit-card {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:93.75%;   /* This is 300px on 320px wide screen */
    max-width:500px;    /* Just to make sure that it doesnt get crazy on bg screens */
    min-width:300px;    /* And make sure that it contains at least some size */
    margin:30px auto;
    padding:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:6px;
    z-index:1;
}

.credit-card .inputs {
    list-style:none;
    margin-top:30px;

}

.credit-card .inputs li {
    margin-bottom:30px;
}


.credit-card .inputs li.last {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.credit-card .inputs li.expire {
    float:left;
    width:70%;
    margin-right:5%;
}

.credit-card .inputs li.expire input{
    float:left;
    width:35%;
}

.credit-card .inputs li.expire input.month{
    width:30%;
    margin-right:5%;
}

.credit-card .inputs li.cvc-code {
    float:right;
    width:20%;


}
.creditcatd .inputs ul.cvc-code{
display: inline;
}

.credit-card .inputs li.cvc-code input {
    width:70%;
}

.credit-card .watermark {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10;
}

.credit-card form {
    position:relative;
    z-index:50;
}

.credit-card .logo {
    position:absolute;
    top:15px;
    right:20px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:bold;
}
/* === Visa === */
.visa {
    color:#fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.8), inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.visa h2 {
    text-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(17,121,173,0.8);
}

.visa .logo {
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    font-size:2em;
    font-style:italic;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(17,123,173,0.9);
}

.visa .logo:after {
    content:' ';
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:5px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid orange;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}

.visa .watermark {
    bottom:-100px;
    left:-50px;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.06);
    font-size:20em;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
}
/* === Mastercard === */
.mastercard {
    color:#fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.8), inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0px 0px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

.mastercard h2 {
    text-shadow:0px 1px 1px #2D4DAA;
}

.mastercard label {
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
    text-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.mastercard input {
    border:1px solid rgba(39,70,157,0.8);
}

.mastercard .logo div {
    float:left;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    border-radius:15px;
    background:rgba(239,209,57,0.8);
}

.mastercard .logo div:first-child 
{
    background:rgba(223,40,40,0.8);
    margin-right:-10px;
}

.mastercard .watermark {
    bottom:-130px;
    left:15%;
}

.mastercard .watermark div {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius:100px;
    background:rgba(239,209,57,0.1);
}

.mastercard .watermark div:first-child {
    background:rgba(223,40,40,0.1);
    margin-right:-60px;
}
/* === Forms === */
label {
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:8px;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 2px rgba(17,123,173,0.6);
}

input {
    display:block;
    padding:10px 8px;
    color:#999;
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-shadow:1px  1px 1px #fff;
    border:1px solid rgba(16,103,133,0.6);
    box-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius:3px;
}

input.full {
    width:100%;
}


/* === Gradients === */
.gr-visa {
    background: #1db1cf; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1db1cf 0%, #1078ab 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1db1cf), color-stop(100%,#1078ab)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1db1cf 0%,#1078ab 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #1db1cf 0%,#1078ab 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1db1cf 0%,#1078ab 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1db1cf 0%,#1078ab 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1db1cf', endColorstr='#1078ab',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.gr-mastercard {
    background: #4d86ce; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #4d86ce 0%, #2d4daa 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#4d86ce), color-stop(100%,#2d4daa)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #4d86ce 0%,#2d4daa 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #4d86ce 0%,#2d4daa 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #4d86ce 0%,#2d4daa 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #4d86ce 0%,#2d4daa 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4d86ce', endColorstr='#2d4daa',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.gr-input {
    background: #d3d3d3; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #d3d3d3 0%, #d9d9d9 38%, #e5e5e5 82%, #e7e7e7 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#d3d3d3), color-stop(38%,#d9d9d9), color-stop(82%,#e5e5e5), color-stop(100%,#e7e7e7)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #d3d3d3 0%,#d9d9d9 38%,#e5e5e5 82%,#e7e7e7 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #d3d3d3 0%,#d9d9d9 38%,#e5e5e5 82%,#e7e7e7 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #d3d3d3 0%,#d9d9d9 38%,#e5e5e5 82%,#e7e7e7 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #d3d3d3 0%,#d9d9d9 38%,#e5e5e5 82%,#e7e7e7 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#d3d3d3', endColorstr='#e7e7e7',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}








.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 28px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: white #f7f7f7 #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06));
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
.dropdown:before, .dropdown:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 9px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 4px dashed;
  border-color: #888 transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.dropdown:before {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-top: none;
}
.dropdown:after {
  margin-top: 7px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.dropdown-select {
  position: relative;
  width: 130%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 10px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #62717a;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
  /* Fallback for IE 8 */
  background: #f2f2f2;
  /* "transparent" doesn't work with Opera */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.dropdown-select:focus {
  z-index: 3;
  width: 100%;
  color: #394349;
  outline: 2px solid #49aff2;
  outline: 2px solid -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
.dropdown-select > option {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  text-shadow: none;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Fix for IE 8 putting the arrows behind the select element. */
.lt-ie9 .dropdown {
  z-index: 1;
}
.lt-ie9 .dropdown-select {
  z-index: -1;
}
.lt-ie9 .dropdown-select:focus {
  z-index: 3;
}

/* Dirty fix for Firefox adding padding where it shouldn't. */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .dropdown-select {
    padding-left: 6px;
  }
}
.fsSubmitButton
{
float:left;
width:20%;
padding: 7px 12px 8px !important;
font-size: 15px !important;
background-color: #57d6c7;
font-weight: bold;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #57D6C7;
color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #57D6C7;
cursor: pointer;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
}
.fsSubmitButtonM
{
float:left;
width:20%;
padding: 7px 12px 8px !important;
font-size: 15px !important;
background-color: #3dbdae;
font-weight: bold;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #57D6C7;
color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #57D6C7;
cursor: pointer;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
}
```

http://fethr.com/paymentpage/creditcard.html

this shows its demo,it has two forms,but one form,visa form may be shown as default.If a number starting with 9 is entered,the css should be changed

I made a javascript which can switch the form by clicking link,here inseadof clicking the link,the form should change with input given in credit card field

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // Switch cards
    jQuery('.switchCard').click(function(e){
        var newCard = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        e.preventDefault();

        jQuery('.cards li.active').fadeOut('fast',function(){
            jQuery(this).removeClass('active');
            jQuery(newCard).fadeIn('fast',function(){
                jQuery(newCard).addClass('active');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I just need the modification of the above javascript which can switch the card with input given

Answer (score 1):

You have two forms, and all the elements in the two forms have the same names, and there are two different "card_number" inputs in two forms, and when someone types a number in one of those inputs you'd like to switch forms, and it would be a lot easier if you at least just had one input for the card number, and then showed the rest of the elements based on that etc.

Anyway, something like this :

```
$('.mastercard').hide();

$('[name="card_number"]').on('keyup', function() {
    if ( this.value.length ) {
        if (this.value.charAt(0) === '4') {
            $('.visa').show();
            $('.mastercard').hide();
        }else if (this.value.charAt(0) === '9') {
            $('.visa').hide();
            $('.mastercard').show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That's because you're bound to have issues with two forms with inputs that has the same name like that, the event handler works on two different elements independently etc.

Comment: do check this www.tomasdostal.com/projects/css3-creditcard/   the above script I have given is working,but i just wanted to convert it to the way